# Taking input from Entry in Tkinter and using it in the back-end

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I have created a code for plotting graphs using csv files and also a Python GUI using Tkinter which is a simple GUI for getting the input from the user and plotting graphs.

Ps. The input a date that is to be added in the back-end file to the file path of csv which is read and plotted.

Here's my code in short:

```
def backend():
    *importing libraries*
    root= Tk()
    inp = tkinter.StringVar()
    e = Entry(root, textvariable=inp)
    e.pack()
    s = inp.get()
    csv = glob.glob("path" + s + "*.csv")
    *rest of the code for plotting graph*
//frontend
*importing libraries*
from file import backend()
root= Tk()
inp = tkinter.StringVar()
e = Entry(root, textvariable=inp)
e.pack()
def submit():
   s = inp.get()
*rest of the frontend code*
```

This code is running without any error but plot is not getting plotted after entering the data in the Tkinter window and clicking the button for plotting graphs.

I also tried by importing the entry variable directly from front-end but it is showing circular input error.
Please help if any ideas.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind an action to make something happen.
I bind the Return key (Enter key) to the 'Entry' widget and added a button. Both will call the 'backend' function:

```
def backend(event=None):
    s = inp.get()
    print(s)


root = Tk()
inp = StringVar()
e = Entry(root, textvariable=inp)
e.pack()
# Return key will call backend
e.bind('<Return>', backend)
# Button will call backend
b = Button(root, text='backend', command=backend)
b.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I'm glad it works for you. When an answer is accepted, one should mark the answer as accepted, and/or vote up the answer. That's the way to tell others that this answer is helpful and it rewards the answer maker with reputation points.

Comment: Thank you for informing. I tried upvoting but since I am new to this upvoting did not work for me.